# Listing all the files in a directory, ignoring folders that meet a pattern? Specifically below a given year?

Tags: r

I want to be able to store a list of all files in a directory for use to build a dataset later, but I need to ignore all files that are in certain folders.  The files I need are all stored by year in separate folders, and using a `pattern` argument isn't a great option as the lengths of file names are inconsistent.

So the easiest way I can think of is to first ignore all folder before a certain year in this step (storing the file list) and then ignore certain files again when I begin to actually read in the files.

Comment: `pattern` accepts regex which can be quite flexible. Do you have a question? Example input and desired output?

Comment: @Gregor Thomas I was hoping to use `list.files` to store the files in this directory for use later, probably in a `lapply` function.  The directory has a subfolder for each year starting in 2000, I only want to list files starting in 2010.  I suppose my question is can I use anything with `list.files` to ignore folders instead of individual files?

Answer (score 1):

Start by listing all directories:

```r
dir_list <- list.dirs()

dir_list
#> [1] "./stuff_2021"       "./things"           "./other_stuff_2015"
```

Then use `grep` to pick out directories that contain four consecutive digits (if the years are abbreviated to two digits, change the regex to `\\d{2}`)

```r
dirs_with_years <- grep("\\d{4}", dir_list, value = TRUE)
dirs_without_years <- grep("\\d{4}", dir_list, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)

dirs_with_years
#> [1] "./stuff_2021"       "./other_stuff_2015"

dirs_without_years
#> [1] "./things"
```

Now extract the four digits from each directory name using `gsub` and convert to numeric:

```
year_of_dir <- as.numeric(gsub("^.*(\\d{4}).*$", "\\1", dirs_with_years))

year_of_dir
#> [1] 2021 2015
```

You can now use `year_of_dir` to filter out the folders you want according to the year:

```r
dirs_before_2020 <- dirs_with_years[year_of_dir < 2020]
dirs_after_2020  <- dirs_with_years[year_of_dir >= 2020]

dirs_before_2020
#> [1] "./other_stuff_2015"

dirs_after_2020
#> [1] "./stuff_2021"
```

If this all seems a bit long-winded, it can easily be compressed into a short function:

```r
get_post_2020_files <- function()
{
  dirs_with_years <- grep("\\d{4}", list.dirs(), value = TRUE)
  year_of_dir <- as.numeric(gsub("^.*(\\d{4}).*$", "\\1", dirs_with_years))
  dirs_with_years[year_of_dir >= 2020]
}

get_post_2020_files()
#> [1] "./stuff_2021"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>